# Next Router Worker uses too much memory

Tags: reactjs, node.js, next.js

My Next.js app uses a lot of server memory. And memory usage is constantly growing. It seems like there is a memory leak in `next-router-worker` process. I see this output of `htop` command on my server: [image: next worker a lot of uses memory]

App is running in production environment and is built according to official documentation. Server node version is 18.18.2.

I've tried changing different version of the Next.js package, but it had no effect.
My current `package.json` is following:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3000",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.32.6",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "axios-extensions": "^3.1.6",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "jotai": "^2.1.0",
    "next": "13.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-currency-input-field": "^3.6.11",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^3.1.0",
    "react-input-mask": "^2.0.4",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/node": "20.2.5",
    "@types/react": "18.2.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.4",
    "@types/react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.5",
    "@types/react-input-mask": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.10",
    "@types/react-transition-group": "^4.4.6",
    "eslint": "8.41.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.4.4",
    "replace-in-file": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  }
}
```

What could be the issue? What could I try except changing versions?

Comment: See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/53571

Answer (score 0):

same here, hosting at Ubuntu 18 at 2cpu 0.5G RAM VPS.

after remove anything related to  API from NextJs.
Replace with the original html  tag will do.
it become less heavy.

- just a very small project with Next-Auth, Mantine JS, and Next JS 13.6.5,
  page just display 300x picture using  API.

[my htop printscreen, that time server before hang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Af2eB.png)